# I renewed my passport and my multiple visa is on my old passport. Will this create problems with Immigration?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, malaysia

I am an Indian national and just renewed my passport. My Malaysian multiple valid visa is on my old passport.

Will this create problems with Immigration? Can I travel with a valid Malaysian visa on an old passport?

Comment: With immigration where? What country was the visa for?

Answer (score 1):

I'm hoping you have the same situation as I did. I had a permanent residency visa (for the UK) in my old expired passport, so just had to take both passports with me when I travelled.

However, I'm not sure about the Malaysian multiple visa. In theory, as long as that visa is still valid, then the passport itself isn't an issue. Just take both with you.

Comment: Most countries are ok with their long term visas being on old passports, unless they explicit mention otherwise. I know only of Canada which has an issue with that.